Make a Laravel App that automatically publish on my page each week
I'm trying to make a Laravel task that will publish a picture each week on my page.
Here's my code:
public function postToFacebook($message, $imageUrl): array|string
    {
        try {
            $response = $this->fb->post('/me/feed', [
                'message' => $message,
                'link' => "https://google.fr",
            ], env('FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN'));

            return $response->getDecodedBody();
        } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            return 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            return 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

I already checked content of $message and env('FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN'), everything is OK.
But I always get :
Undefined array key 1

on post() method.
I am using "facebook/graph-sdk" package.
Is it mandatory to have a FB app up and running ? Mine is not published, but it is asking me a bunch of things, like Business verification that is not very relevant, as I do it for myself...
Do you have any idea how should I fix the issue ?
